# Django CharField primary key doesn't work, creating rowid primary key automatically

Tags: python, django, sqlite, primary-key, rowid

I am using Django models for a SQLite database.

I defined CharField primary key (for example the name of attribute `A`) but the physical database synced by `Django` shows another primary key `rowid` instead of `A`.

I tried dropping the table and re-sync a couple of time but still the same.

Why?

```
class TestTable(models.Model):
    A = models.CharField(max_length=10, primary_key=True, db_column='A')
```

----------------------Edit------------------------

Django version is 1.8.3

Comment: What Django version are you using? If >= 1.8 are your migrations up to date?

Comment: Django would add `id` as primary key not `rowid`. You might have some old db/table/migrations which is causing the behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQLITE databases always create a rowid column by default. This is the actual primary key SQLITE uses for manage the database. This is different from what you see in other SQL databases, but SQLITE is pretty different in more things.

For more info look at https://www.sqlite.org/rowidtable.html

P.S. I know that this is 2 years late, but it might help someone if not OP.